# Define or convert projection when netcdf saved as tif raster?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, netcdf

A netcdf data structure showed as follows:

```
Dimensions:  (lat: 360, lon: 720)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float32 -179.75 -179.25 -178.75 -178.25 -177.75 -177.25 ...
  * lat      (lat) float32 -89.75 -89.25 -88.75 -88.25 -87.75 -87.25 -86.75 ...
    time     datetime64[ns] 1901-01-16
 Data variables:
    cld      (lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    stn      (lat, lon) int32 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
```

[image]

I want to save this layer as `.tif` raster with `wgs84` proj. How to convert the projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a least a few ways to do it:

1. **GDAL command line utilities:**

Since version 2.1 GDAL working fine (read and write) with raster and vector netCDF files. You can use both GDAL command line utilities (*gdal_translate* and *gdalwarp*) to reproject and output to GeoTiff format file.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Float32 -a_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84" input.nc output.tif
```

2. **Execute GDAL utility from Python scripts:**

Here is some example:

```
import subprocess

def convert_netcdf_to_geotiff(infile, outfile, band_number=1, verbose=False):

    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
        return subprocess.check_call([
            "gdal_translate", infile, outfile,
            "-of", "GTiff",
            "-ot", "Float32",
            "-a_srs", "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84",
            "-b", str(band_number)

        ],
            stdout=None if verbose else devnull
        )
```

3. **Also, you can use GDAL utility in Docker container**

If you don't want or can't install/build GDAL on your machine you can use prepared Docker images with GDAL 2.1 version or other versions with support netCDF driver.

There is [one](https://github.com/geo-data/gdal-docker) of the solutions:

```
cd /path/to/dir/with/netCDF/file
docker run -v $(pwd):/data geodata/gdal gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Float32 -a_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84" input.nc output.tif
```